# What is the best way to convert a Ruby string range to a Range object

Tags: ruby

I have some Ruby code which takes dates on the command line in the format:

```
-d 20080101,20080201..20080229,20080301
```

I want to run for all dates between `20080201` and `20080229` inclusive and the other dates present in the list.

I can get the string `20080201..20080229`, so is the best way to convert this to a Range instance? Currently, I am using `eval`, but it feels like there should be a better way.

---

@Purfideas I was kind of looking for a more general answer for converting any string of type `int..int` to a Range I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

But then just do

```
ends = '20080201..20080229'.split('..').map{|d| Integer(d)}
ends[0]..ends[1]
```

anyway I don't recommend eval, for security reasons

Comment: What's the security reason involved with using eval?

Comment: cmd line input is "user input," so can you be this always gets executed by trusted people?  this is the original SQL injection... ask that q in security ... it'll be your highest score ever.
 :)

Answer (score 41):

```
Range.new(*self.split("..").map(&:to_i))
```

Answer (score 7):

Inject with no args works well for two element arrays:

```
rng='20080201..20080229'.split('..').inject { |s,e| s.to_i..e.to_i }
```

Of course, this can be made generic

```
class Range
  def self.from_ary(a)
    a.inject{|s,e| s..e }
  end
end

rng = Range.from_ary('20080201..20080229'.split('..').map{|s| s.to_i})
rng.class  # => Range
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be inject{|s,e| (s.to_i .. e.to_i) } ? 

As written, it returns an Array with a range as a single element instead of a Range.

Comment: Commenting well after the fact, as I did rush to accept the answer, which when I looked at it, then intention made sense, but I admit when I tried it I found the same problem.

Comment: Fixed the syntax so that it correctly now states `a.inject{|s,e| s..e }` without Array square brackets

Answer (score 2):

assuming you want the range to iterate properly through months etc, try

```
require 'date'

ends = '20080201..20080229'.split('..').map{|d| Date.parse(d)}
(ends[0]..ends[1]).each do |d|
  p d.day
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ranger](https://github.com/Epigene/ranger) uses regex to validate strings with no SQL injection fear, and then `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Purfideas answer with another answer somewhere on StackOverflow, I solved this by also surrounding the code with an input check, so the only thing used is a valid enumerable

```
if !value[/^[0-9]+\.\.[0-9]+$/].nil?
    ends = value.split('..').map{|d| Integer(d)}
    value = ends[0]..ends[1]
end
```

It essentially rewrites your string value to a enumerable value. This comes in handy if you add a enumerable field in a yaml config file.

If you need it for your application, you could extend the regex with an optional third literal dot, that could be optional.

Answer (score 0):

If we do it like

```
v= "20140101..20150101"
raise "Error: invalid format: #{v}" if /\d{8}\.\.\d{8}/ !~ v
r= eval(v)
```

and the attacker has a way of bypassing the raise check (simply by means of manipulating the runtime to disable exceptions) then we can get a dangerous eval which will potentially destroy the universe.

So for the sake of reducing attack vectors, we check the format, and then do the parsing manually, then check the results

```
v= "20140101..20150101"
raise "Error: invalid format: #{v}" if /\d{8}\.\.\d{8}/ !~ v
r= Range.new(*v.split(/\.\./).map(&:to_i))
raise "Error: invalid range: #{v}" if r.first> r.last
```

Answer (score 0):

Here suppose you want to store the hash as a system constant value and fetch it in any model. The hash key will be a range value.

```
hash_1 = {1..5 => 'a', 6..12 => 'b', 13..67 => 'c', 68..9999999 => 'd'}
```

Then create the system constant with value as hash_1.to_json.
.to_json will convert your hash object to JSON object.
Now inside the code create a new hash hash_2,

```
JSON.parse(SystemConstant.get('Constant_name')).each{|key,val| temp_k=key.split('..').map{|d| Integer(d)}; hash_2[temp_k[0]..temp_k[1]] = val}
```

The new hash_2 will be the required hash_1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement although in my case the strings were in two possible formats, occasionally they were single number strings such as "7", other times they were ranges such as "10-14". Either way I wanted to turn the string into an Enumerable collection of numbers.

My approach (inspired by the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243732/145725)) was:

```ruby
def numbers(from_string:)
  if from_string.include?('-')
    return Range.new(*from_string.split('-').map(&:to_i))
  else
    return [from_string.to_i] # put number in an array so we can enumerate over it
  end
end
```

It can also be done as a (long) one-liner if you think that's more readable:

```ruby
from_string.include?('-') ? Range.new(*from_string.split('-').map(&:to_i)) : [from_string.to_i]
```

I was processing a long list of known strings, not dealing with arbitrary user input so this doesn't guard against malicious input.

Comment: there's an extra : in the long one-liner. I believe it should be: `from_string.include?('-') ? Range.new(*from_string.split('-').map(&:to_i)) : [from_string.to_i]`