# Passing age range values in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand how to perform a specific age search, what I need help with is passing in params an age range search.

With the code below params outputs as: `age=18&age=25`

I instead would like for it to search users 18..25, as oppose to specific age values 18 and 25.

```
  .select1
                    .col.col3.col33 style='width:175px;'
                      label Ages
                      = select_tag :age, options_for_select((18..65),18), {class: 'small'}

                  .select5
                    .col.col4
                      label to
                      = select_tag :age, options_for_select((20..65),65), {class: 'small'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two select tags with the same name (`:age`), they'll overwrite eachother.

Try something like this:

```
= select_tag :start_age ...
= select_tag :end_age ...
```

Then in your controller (assuming you have a model `User` with an attribute `age`):

```
User.where(age: params[:start_age]..params[:end_age])
```

The `..` syntax denotes a range, e.g. `5..10` means `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. Passing a range to `where` means "give me all users whose age is a value in this range."

Depending on how complicated your controller is you might also want to extract the "range" logic to its own method:

```
def index
  @users = User.where(age: user_age_range)
  ...
end


.
.
.

private

def user_age_range
  params[:start_age]..params[:end_age]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

pass age rage value like `age=18..25`check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53588/517483 how to parse it in conroller and covert to range